# Read file in java

Tags: java, io

I have file in my computer which have `.file` extension , I want to read it 9 character by 9 character. I know that I can read file by this code, but what should I do when my file is not `.txt`?does java support to read `.file` s with this code?

```
                InputStream is = null;
                InputStreamReader isr = null;
                BufferedReader br = null;
                is = new FileInputStream("c:/test.txt");
                // create new input stream reader
                isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                // create new buffered reader
                br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                // creates buffer
                char[] cbuf = new char[is.available()];
                for (int i = 0; i < 90000000; i += 9) {
                // reads characters to buffer, offset i, len 9
                br.read(cbuf, i, 9);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension of a file is totally irrelevant. Extensions like `.txt` are mere conventions to help your operating system choose the right program when you open it.

So you can store text in any file (`.txt`, `.file`, `.foobar` if you are so inclined...), provided *you* know what kind of data it contains, and read it accordingly from your program.

So yes, Java can read `.file` files, and your code will work fine if that file contains text.

Answer (score 0):

> does java support to read .file s with this code?

No, since `c:/test.txt` is hard coded. If it wouldn't yes it would support it.

Comment: The answer is "Yes". See the other answers.

Comment: @user1803551 and thats what i said.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible if you write `is = new FileInputStream("c:/test.file");`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it reads any file you give it the same way. You can pass any file path with any extension to the `FileInputStream` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can read any file you want, since a file is just a sequence of bytes. The extension tells you in what format the bytes should be read, so when we have a `.txt` file we know that this is a file with sequences of characters.

When you have a file format called `.file` we know that it should be (according to you) a 9x9 set of characters. This way we know what to read and do that.

Since the `.file` format is characters I would say yes, you can read that with your code for instance with this:

```
public String[] readFileFormat (final File file) throws IOException {
    if (file.exists()) {
        final String[] lines = new String[9];
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader( file ) );
        for ( int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++ ) {
            lines[i] = reader.readLine();
            if (lines[i] == null || lines[i].isEmpty() || lines[i].length() < 9)
                throw new RuntimeException ("Line is empty when it should be filled!");
            else if (lines[i].length() > 9)
                throw new RuntimeException ("Line does not have exactly 9 characters!");
        }
        reader.close();
        return lines;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The extension is totally irrelevant, so it can be .file, .txt or whatever you want it to be.

Here is an example of reading in a file with BuffereInputStream that reads a file of type .file. This is part of a larger guide that discusses [15 ways to read files in Java](https://funnelgarden.com/java_read_file/).

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFile_BufferedInputStream_Read {
  public static void main(String [] pArgs) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String fileName = "c:\\temp\\sample-10KB.file";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    try (BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream)) {
      int singleCharInt;
      char singleChar;
      while((singleCharInt = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        singleChar = (char) singleCharInt;
        System.out.print(singleChar);
      }
    }
  }
}
```